# Como saber si a un DIV ya no le caben más elementos dentro de él, teniendo en cuenta su altura?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Supongamos que tengo un div:

```
<div id="page1" class="contenedor-page" style="height: 1200px; width: 580px; overflow-y: hidden;"></div>
```

Y dentro de ese div, voy añadiendo elementos, de la siguiente manera:

```
var templateText = `<div id="elemento-text1" class="elemento-editable">Marcador de texto</div>`;

$('#page1').append(templateText);
```

> Con el `código` de arriba voy añadiendo elementos dentro del `DIV padre` con la clase: `'contenedor-page'`, como utilizo la palabra reservada `'append'` los elementos se van a ir agregando uno debajo del otro y así sucesivamente.

**Tener en cuenta:** Que el `DIV padre` con la clase `'contenedor-page'` tiene una altura de `1200px`, además de eso se le `inhabilita el scroll Y`, con el estilo: `overflow-y: hidden.`

**Ahora:** lo que quiero detectar, es que cuando ya no quepan más elementos dentro del `DIV padre`, *es decir:* como el `DIV padre` tiene `1200px` altura y no tiene `scroll`, a medida de que yo vaya agregando elementos, pues estos se van a salir cuando alcancen la altura máxima del DIV padre, entonces quisiera saber cuando ya no quepan más elementos dentro de él, y pues hay mandar una alerta que diga que ya no caben mas elementos y que no permita agregarlos.

> Solo quisiera saber como detectar cuando ya no quepan mas elementos dentro de un div padre, teniendo en cuenta su altura.

Espero me ayuden por favor, puede ser con Jquery o Javascript.

De antemano muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Entiendo que la altura de los hijos es constante, ¿no?

Comment: No se muy bien a que te refieres, pero los DIV que voy agregando osea los HIJOS, tienen una altura fija.

Comment: Si conoces la cantidad de elementos que tiene dentro el div y la altura de cada uno, con javascript solo sería sumar esas alturas y comparar el total con la altura del div

Comment: Listo!!! ya me diste la idea de como realizar eso, muchas gracias!

Comment: Pero es que es más, si conoces la altura del padre `1200px` y la de los hijos, ni tienes que hacer ningún cálculo en js. Si los hijos son `400px`, ya sabes que sólo pueden haber 3, así que controlas por la cantidad de hijos, no por la altura, que es más correcto por diversos motivos, uno de ellos, porque no todas las pantallas son iguales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes del `append` para añadir más elementos tendrías que comprobar el tamaño de los elementos ya añadidos.

Para eso puedes usar la función [`outerHeight()`](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/#outerHeight-includeMargin) the jQuery.

Cuando sepas la altura de cada hijo, solo tienes que sumar y y ver si es mayor que la altura del `div` padre, o sea, 1200 en este caso.